# Why doesn't Interface Builder see my class in the static framework?

Tags: swift, uiview, frameworks, interface-builder, static-libraries

There is a Cocoa framework project called `MyFramework` with Mach-O Type set to `Static Library` that features `MyView.swift` with a following declaration:

```
open class MyView: UIView { /* ... */ }
```

In the meantime, another project called `MyApp` statically links against the static framework `MyFramework`. Additionally, `Main.storyboard` of `MyApp` has a scene in which there is a view, whose custom class is set to `MyView` and module is set to `MyFramework`.

Whenever the view controller that backs this scene is instantiated, the view behaves as a default `UIView` and I see the message in console:

```
2018-06-23 18:22:29.114096+0700 MyApp[2318:415810] Unknown class _TtC15MyFramework15MyView in Interface Builder file.
```

Then, I add to `MyApp`'s target a `MyNewView.swift` with the following declaration:

```
class MyNewView: MyView {  }
```

Without changing anything in the `Main.storyboard`, I launch the app, the `MyView` class gets instantiated, it behaves as supposed and the message doesn't appear.

Question #1: why does this happen? Is the type stripped or not registered with the Objective-C runtime if it's not directly imported or referenced from anywhere in code? Or maybe is it somehow lazily loaded?

Question #2: what can I do with it so that I don't need to apply such workarounds?

**Update**: I restarted the Xcode and the issue did not persist, yet still, the interface builder doesn't suggest `MyFramework` as a module while typing in the `Module` field in view's identity properties, and the `@IBInspectable`s of `MyView` don't get parsed, don't show up in the interface builder, in the view's attributes.

Comment: tumbleweed badge lol

Comment: Did you ever find out what the answer to this was?

Comment: @Jmf yes, I have - as states in the edit I just sorta resaved the storyboard, the project, cleaned, shut xcode down, reboot the computer, open the project, build, and it worked